# No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils and raise SystemExit, "error: " + str(msg)

Tags: python, numpy, mingw32

Could somebody save me?? When I was compiling Python with some c code, using the MinGw32, I was stacked by the following problems.

```
D:\java_workspace\Dilrechete\ddst\video\view_cv.py:73: FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.
if frame==None: return False
D:\java_workspace\Dilrechete\ddst\video\colour_bias.py:102: FutureWarning: comparison to    `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.
if img==None:
No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\java_workspace\Dilrechete\ddst\video\test_backsub_dp.py", line 127, in <module>
man.run(profile=True)
File "D:\java_workspace\Dilrechete\ddst\video\manager.py", line 127, in run
if self.nextFrame()==False: break
File "D:\java_workspace\Dilrechete\ddst\video\manager.py", line 104, in nextFrame
res = vid.nextFrame()
File "D:\java_workspace\Dilrechete\ddst\video\colour_bias.py", line 162, in nextFrame
weave.inline(code, ['img', 'output', 'matrix', 'lumScale', 'chromaScale', 'noiseFloor'])
File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\inline_tools.py", line 366, in inline
**kw)
File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\inline_tools.py", line 496, in   compile_function
verbose=verbose, **kw)
File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\ext_tools.py", line 373, in compile
verbose=verbose, **kw)
File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\build_tools.py", line 279, in build_extension
setup(name=module_name, ext_modules=[ext],verbose=verb)
File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
return old_setup(**new_attr)
File "E:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 166, in setup
raise SystemExit, "error: " + str(msg)
distutils.errors.CompileError: error: Command "g++ -O2 -Wall -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x0900 -  IE:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave -IE:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\scxx - IE:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IE:\Python27\include -IE:\Python27\PC -c  E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\scxx\weave_imp.cpp -o  c:\users\tsinghua\appdata\local\temp\scipy-tsinghua-ivodx3\python27_intermediate\compiler_e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb924\Release\python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\scxx\weave_imp.o" failed with exit status 1

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

There are three main problems, one is the "No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", one is "raise SystemExit, "error: " + str(msg)" and the last is"
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information."

I've tried many ways, but neither of them works for me. So I paste all the problems up here, can somebody tells me how to fix it?